# How can I change the finder background color on mac Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Every post I've seen says to open a finder, click view > Show View Options, and there is a background section to change the color of thew background. But when I go into show view options all it has is arrange by:, sort by: and text size.

Did the background option get moved? If not what can I do to make it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background option only appears in Show View Options when you set View > icons.

Comment: Hmm looks like your right. Well that sucks...